# Path to exec folder in bash script within .app container

Tags: macos, bash, shell, .app

I'm trying to make a .app that will run a simple bash script to launch a java app.
I found instructions for making a suitable .app container and running the .app runs my bash. Great.

The problem is, I want to put my java app inside the .app but i'm not sure how to get my bash script to launch it.

Here's my current script:

```
#! /bin/sh

/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -jar -Xmx1g javaapp.jar&
```

The script runs and shuts down immediately. I'm assuming because it either can't find `/java` or `javaapp.jar` which I put in the .app container in the same folder as the bash script (`MacOS`)

Comment: You meant to type a space before the trailing ampersand?

Comment: That made no difference, thanks.

Comment: Begin your script with `#!/bin/bash -x` which will give you debug output. Then you can see what's happening.

Comment: There's nowhere for the debug to go though. It doesn't open a shell.

Comment: Valid point... I'm assuming you checked to see that the script is executable? Also, would you mind posting a link to the instructions you followed so we can replicate?

Comment: This was how I created it, https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shell-script-mac-apps it simply makes the correct folder structure. I have confirmed that the script runs by adding `osascript -e "tell app \"System Events\" to display dialog \"Testing\""`

Comment: Add `1>>/Users/[you]/jar.log 2>&1` to the end of the line calling the jar. Then you'll get any output from the command (stdout or stderr) written to a logfile. That may at least give you a hint if there's a problem with starting the jar. Also, you're starting the jar with an &, to run it in the background. Maybe you want to start it with `nohup` as well so it doesn't get closed when the parent script completes (e.g. `nohup command args >> output.log 2>&1 &`).

Comment: Thanks. If I put the .jar on my Desktop and put the path in the bash, it works fine. If I put it in the .app bundle next to the bash and use ./my.jar I get Error: Unable to access jarfile ./my.jar